# Gene Golovchinsky RIP

Tags: discussion

I'm really sorry to say that I discovered that [Gene Golovchinsky](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/8/gene-golovchinsky), one of the most active users and biggest supporters of our Genealogy SE, [passed away relatively suddenly on August 15.](http://genegolovchinsky.blogspot.ca/2013/08/remembering-gene.html)

My sympathies to his family and friends. We'll miss him as well.

Comment: I'm very sorry to hear this. My sympathies to those who knew him.

Comment: So sad to hear this. I have been wondering and worrying about him, since he was so positive about this site. Blessings to his loved ones.

Comment: This is sad. I am no Genealogy SE user of the early days, but I often stumbled upon Gene Golovchinsky’s answers and questions when browsing this site. His input was extremely valuable. Thank you for that and all the best for his family and friends.

Comment: Thankyou for bringing this to all of our attentions, Gene was certainly a great contributor to Genealogy SE let alone elsewhere so I was very sorry to hear of his passing.  I wondered whether some words could be added to his user page to honour that and just read this [Meta StackOverflow Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled) that may interest others.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Well, I took a look at the MetaSO question you link to and was surprised to find that the number one voted answer is that we shouldn't do that.

Comment: I provided the link simply as food for thought.  Personally, I think that the concise, yet sensitive, announcement you made here could be easily transferred to Gene's user page if that were found to be in line with the wishes of his family and friends.